# iptable rule to match system service

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I have this rule:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner myuser -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

But instead of matching with a user, I would like to match with a system service.
Cold you help me?

Comment: Please show what you have tried or at least traces of a minute amount of research pertaining to the issue at hand.